# Ruby gem not found when target script is spawned by another ruby script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium, rubygems, watir-webdriver

I've a watir script that I want to fire off from a Rails app on demand. My controller action looks something like this:

```
def run_scrape
  pid = Process.spawn('C:\Ruby22-x64\bin\ruby.exe "C:\Users\Admin\Dropbox\dev\watir-scripts\ds-vin.rb" 3VWB07AJ')
  Process.detach(pid)
  true
end
```

The actual script starts with:

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
b = Watir::Browser.new :ie
# etc
```

Now, if I navigate to the folder and just run the script directly, everything works fine. Once it's triggered from Rails (which is at a different location; seems like that's messing it up) I'm greeted with the following error:

> `require': cannot load such file -- watir-webdriver (LoadError)

Watir-webdriver is in my gem list. I'm also requiring a couple of .rb files in the same folder, which was a problem until I used `require_relative`. I'm missing something simple here, I think. How do I `require_relative` a global gem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First solution is to run your scraper in the same process as Rails, but in a different thread:

```
require 'C:\Users\Admin\Dropbox\dev\watir-scripts\ds-vin.rb'
thr = Thread.new do 
    b = Watir::Browser.new :ie
    ...
end
```

Second is to fix your environment if you are going to use `Process.spawn` - assuming your gems are installed system-wide you can do something like

```
ENV['GEM_PATH'] = "c:/Ruby220/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0"
```

at the top of your `ds-vin.rb` script. To find the exact gem path you should use, make sure you run `gem which watir-webdriver` and `gem environment` and copy from there.

Comment: Is it possible to detach from the thread? I don't really want any of the scraper code in Rails.

Comment: Also, the ENV['GEM_HOME'] doesnt seem to work for either of the paths under "Gem Paths"

Comment: did you set `GEM_HOME` before doing your `require` in `ds-vin.rb`?

Comment: Updated answer to use `GEM_PATH`. Plz post the output of `gem which watir-webdriver` as well.

Comment: the output was: `C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/watir-webdriver-0.9.1/lib/watir-webdriver.rb`; however with literally no changes the script magically started working. I even reversed the steps to try and break it again - nothing.